# Cannot connect to localdb in an azure pipelines task on a hosted agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, localdb

Cannot connect to a running localdb instance in an azure pipeline. Running on the following image: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019.

When trying to run SQLCMD I get the following error:

```
SQLCMD : Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to 
SQL Server [2].
```

I am not sure how to specify the connection I have tried a few things.

The following is my azure-pipelines.yml

```
variables:
  solution: 'source/**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  dbInstance: 'MSSQLLocalDB'
  dbShare: 'MSSQLLocalDBShare'
  attachDb: 'azure\attachDB.sql'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      SQLLOCALDB START $(dbInstance)
      SQLLOCALDB SHARE $(dbInstance) $(dbShare)
      SQLLOCALDB INFO $(dbInstance)
      SQLCMD -s ((sqllocaldb info $(dbInstance) | Select-String -Pattern "Instance pipe name") -split " ")[3] -i $(attachDb)
```

For the 'SQLCMD' line I have also tried the following and get the same error:

```
 SQLCMD -s "(localdb)\.\MSSQLLocalDBShare" -i "azure\attachDB.sql"
```

Here is the output from info:

```
LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" started.
Private LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" shared with the shared name: "MSSQLLocalDBShare".

Name:               MSSQLLocalDB
Version:            13.1.4001.0
Shared name:        MSSQLLocalDBShare
Owner:              fv-az8\VssAdministrator
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Running
Last start time:    7/9/2019 3:36:04 PM
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#238E1FEF\tsql\query
```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/issues/194 or https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/issues/1409 might help. Depends if they're the same issue

Comment: These links 404 now

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using the `Invoke-SqlCmd` cmdlet instead? Under the hood, it still calls SQLCMD but this one's easier to tame.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
  SQLLOCALDB START $(dbInstance)
  SQLLOCALDB SHARE $(dbInstance) $(dbShare)
  SQLLOCALDB INFO $(dbInstance)

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $(attachDb) -ConnectionString "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=false;" -Verbose'
```